# Перевод русского текста из кодировки Unicode (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.x

Иностранцы получают из России письма на русском, при этом кодировка напрочь сбивается и выдается в Юникоде.

исходный "текст" письма:

> %u0421%u043A%u0430%u043D%u0435%u0440 %u043F%u0440%u0438 %u0437%u0430%u043F%u0443%u0441%u043A%u0435 %u0432%u044B%u0434%u0430%u0435%u0442 %u043E%u0448%u0438%u0431%u043A%u0443, %u043D%u0435

мой скрипт:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

p_text = str.lower(raw_input())

dict_utf = {
'u0410': 'А', 'u0430': 'а',
'u0411': 'Б', 'u0431': 'б',
'u0412': 'В', 'u0432': 'в',
'u0413': 'Г', 'u0433': 'г',
'u0414': 'Д', 'u0434': 'д',
'u0415': 'Е', 'u0435': 'е',
'u0401': 'Ё', 'u0451': 'ё',
'u0416': 'Ж', 'u0436': 'ж',
'u0417': 'З', 'u0437': 'з',
'u0418': 'И', 'u0438': 'и',
'u0419': 'Й', 'u0439': 'й',
'u041a': 'К', 'u043a': 'к',
'u041b': 'Л', 'u043b': 'л',
'u041c': 'М', 'u043c': 'м',
'u041d': 'Н', 'u043d': 'н',
'u041e': 'О', 'u043e': 'о',
'u041f': 'П', 'u043f': 'п',
'u0420': 'Р', 'u0440': 'р',
'u0421': 'С', 'u0441': 'с',
'u0422': 'Т', 'u0442': 'т',
'u0423': 'У', 'u0443': 'у',
'u0424': 'Ф', 'u0444': 'ф',
'u0425': 'Х', 'u0445': 'х',
'u0426': 'Ц', 'u0446': 'ц',
'u0427': 'Ч', 'u0447': 'ч',
'u0428': 'Ш', 'u0448': 'ш',
'u0429': 'Щ', 'u0449': 'щ',
'u042a': 'Ъ', 'u044a': 'ъ',
'u042d': 'Ы', 'u044b': 'ы',
'u042c': 'Ь', 'u044c': 'ь',
'u042d': 'Э', 'u044d': 'э',
'u042e': 'Ю', 'u044e': 'ю',
'u042f': 'Я', 'u044f': 'я',
}

x = ''
for key in dict_utf:    
    if key in p_text:    
        x += dict_utf.get(key)    
print x
```

вбиваю текст из письма, выводит пока только "Скрена", т.е. нарушена последовательность, т.к. делаю отбор из словаря сначала, иначе, если по фразе перебирать, он перебирает посимвольно.

как привести все в приемлемый для человека вид?

Если есть другой вариант, при помощи encode, его тоже интересно узнать.

Comment: unrelated: следует заметить, что Unicode это не кодировка. `unicode` тип в Питоне представляет последовательность Юникодных символов (Unicode codepoints), что заметно отличается от `bytes` типа, представляющего последовательность байтов (целые числа от 0 до 255 здесь). Одну и ту же Юникодную строчку можно закодировать в байты, используя разные кодировки (и результат может быть разным), `bytestring = unicode_text.encode(character_encoding)` и в обратную сторону: `unicode_text = bytestring.decode(character_encoding)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> x = '%u0421%u043A%u0430%u043D%u0435%u0440 %u043F%u0440%u0438'
>>> y = x.replace('%', '\\').decode('unicode-escape')
>>> print y
>>>
Сканер при
>>>
>>> type(y)
<type 'unicode'>
```

Нагуглено тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094380/python-unicode-string-stored-as-u84b8-u6c7d-u5730-in-file-how-to-convert-it

Comment: супер! спасибо, @andy.37 , по ссылке тоже полезные примеры и решения. буду дальше изучать stackoverflow

Comment: @Serg: это редкий случай когда использование `'unicode-escape'` является уместным ([примите ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), если это решение работает в Вашем случае). В общем случае, наличие `'unicode-escape'` в коде указывает на проблему с форматом данных: вместо использования unicode-escape, необходимо починить генерацию данных (например, JSON формат использовать).

Comment: @jfs, абсолютно согласен, вообще выражение "кодировка напрочь сбивается и выдается в Юникоде" повергает меня в трепет.

Answer (score 0):

```
input_file_path = input("Введите путь к входному файлу в формате Unicode: ")
output_file_path = "out_" + input_file_path

with open(input_file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as input_file:
    content = input_file.read()

text_content = ""
for char in content:
    if ord(char) in dict_utf:
        text_content += dict_utf[ord(char)]

with open(output_file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as output_file:
    output_file.write(text_content)

print(f"Файл успешно сконвертирован и сохранен по пути: {output_file_path}")
```

В этом коде мы сначала запрашиваем у пользователя путь к входному файлу в формате Unicode. Затем мы открываем файл для чтения с указанием кодировки utf-8 и читаем его содержимое в переменную content. Далее мы итерируемся по каждому символу char в content, проверяем его порядковое значение с помощью ord(char). Если порядковое значение есть в `dict_utf`, мы добавляем соответствующий символ в переменную `text_content`.

Наконец, мы открываем новый файл для записи с префиксом "`out_`" и сохраняем в него содержимое переменной `text_content` с использованием кодировки utf-8. Выводится сообщение о успешном сохранении файла.

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что в этом коде я использую функцию input() вместо `raw_input()` и добавил указание кодировки `encoding="utf-8"` при открытии файлов для обработки символов настоящей кодировкой Unicode.

Comment: [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Answer (score 0):

```
import codecs

input_file_path = input("Введите путь к входному файлу в формате Unicode: ")
output_file_path = "out_" + input_file_path

with codecs.open(input_file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="replace") as input_file:
    content = input_file.read()

text_content = ""
for char in content:
    if ord(char) > 127:
        if ord(char) in dict_utf:
            text_content += dict_utf[ord(char)]
        else:
            text_content += f"\\u{ord(char):04x}"
    else:
        text_content += char

with codecs.open(output_file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as output_file:
    output_file.write(text_content)

print(f"Файл успешно сконвертирован и сохранен по пути: {output_file_path}")
```

Comment: стоило не публиковать новый ответ, а дополнить ваш предыдущий