# Как декодировать b'\u0417\u0434\u0440\u0430' строку в python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть строка примерно с таким содержанием: `b'\\u0417\\u0434\\u0440\\u0430'`
Как декодировать ее? Кодировка utf-8.

P.S. это именно строка, а не bytes

Comment: [гляньте здесь](http://www.py-my.ru/post/4bfb3c6a1d41c846bc00009b)

Comment: @ТимурВалиев там просто как из стороки "слово" сделать перевод в тип bytes. Но у меня код utf не в bytes представлены, а в string

Comment: [может здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487400/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-unicode-python)? Ребята уже здесь с этим сталкивались

Comment: @АндрейАнтипов, это не UTF-8, А UTF-16. Почувствуйте разницу.

Comment: Какой тип у вашей "строки"? Покажите: `print(type(data))` и `print(ascii(data))`. Откуда данные пришли? (если это часть json, то не нужно руками парсить, используйте json-парсер)

Comment: @PashaPash: `"b'\u0417'" != b'\\u0417'"` в Питоне (у автора может во вводе именно `\\u` и есть, но из вопроса это не ясно).

Comment: @jfs но дело в том что я только добавил одинарные кавычки. слеши я не допечатывал. удвоение слешей, судя по всему, баг редактора :(

Comment: @jfs точнее, не баг - "фича". скорее всего у автора были двойные слеши, и он просто не заметил что их съел парсер, вместе с переносами строк. В любом случае, теперь никто не узнает что там было. Закрою вопрос по причине неизвестности.

Comment: @PashaPash: REPL в Питоне удваивает слеши (`repr` неявно вызывается), поэтому не ясно, что там было (cъедание слешей могло правильно показывать строку -- одна "фича" исправляла другую "фичу"). Без `print(ascii(data))` я не могу сказать что на входе. К примеру, `len(json.loads('"\\\\"')) == 1`. [Как json-данные \u0413\u0440... преобразовать в русский текст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/606885/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как отметил в комментарии [Тимур Валиев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190461/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%80-%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2), [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487400/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-unicode-python) описано решение похожей задачи. В вашем случае надо сделать так:

```
>>>> string = "b'\\u0417\\u0434\\u0440\\u0430'"
>>>> print(string[2:-1].encode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape'))
Здра
```