# Как json-данные \u0413\u0440... преобразовать в русский текст

Tags: python, json, кодировка, unicode, python-2.7

Здравствуйте. Возникла проблема с кодировкой. Получаю JSON и не могу его декодировать в Русский текст.
Данные такого формата: `\u0413\u0440\u0430\u0439\u0440`.
Как преобразовать их в русский текст? `decode("utf-8")` не работает, `unichr` и `char` тоже... Использую python 2.7

Получаю данные так:

```
response = urllib.urlopen('Ссылка') #получение json
data = json.loads(response.read()) #Обработка JSOn запроса
```

Comment: А какой версией питона вы пользуетесь?

Comment: использую python 2.7

Comment: Посмотрите тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487400/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-unicode-python/487417#487417. Возможно, и сам сайт криво отдает.

Comment: Вы уверены, что это именно данные такие, а не просто сам питон экранирует строку при печати для вашего терминала? Как вы проверяете, какие даннве записаны?

Answer (score 2):

Ничего не надо делать. `data` уже Юникодные строчки с русским текстом содержит.

```
#!/use/bin/env python2
import json
from urllib2 import urlopen 

data = json.load(urlopen(url))
print data['text']
```

Наиболее вероятной причиной, по которой вы видите \u0440 вместо `р` в Питоне 2, является *печать контейнера вместо строки*. К примеру если `type(data['text']) == list`:

```
>>> print [u'\u0440']
[u'\u0440']
>>> print repr(u'\u0440')
u'\u0440'
>>> print [u'\u0440'][0]
р
>>> print u'\u0440'
р
```

Связано:

- [Как вывести в консоль русские символы c выполняемой программы на python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/580971/23044)
- [Removing u in list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33423708/4279).

---

Если `type(data['text'])` является `unicode`, но вы всё равно видите \u0413\u0440 на экране вместо `Гр`, то либо данные неверно генерируются (посмотрите на `print repr(urlopen(url).read())`—не должны `\\u` видеть, правильно только один слэш, а не два), либо печать Unicode в вашем окружении так сконфигурирована (проверьте значение PYTHONIOENCODING переменной окружения—`ascii:backslashreplace` может `Г` в `\u0413` превратить). Вот [примеры ввода/вывода Unicode в Питоне 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/414060/23044).

О `\u` в json cм. ещё ответ на связанный вопрос: [Json ответ в "неправильной кодировке" отображает русские символы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/378941/23044).

`\u` экранирование используется для представления Unicode символов как в JSON формате так и в текстовом представлении unicode строк в Питоне.

Answer (score 0):

Я делал так, используя opener.
Это кусочек из проекта на Python 3, так что не уверен, но в основном оно выглядит так:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib.request, http.cookiejar, requests, json
cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
content = json.loads(opener.open(urllib.request.unquote("ссылка")).read().decode('utf-8'))
```

В итоге json должен содержать кириллицу.

Comment: в python 2.7 нет `urllib.request` точнее модуля `request` в `urllib`

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так:

```
>>> print '\u0413\u0440\u0430\u0439\u0440'.replace('\u','\\u').decode('unicode-escape')
Грайр
```