# No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json, python-2.x, python-2.7

В результате чтения json-файла, python выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\guest_user\Documents\test json code.py", line 8, in <module>
    fgh = json.loads(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Скрипт:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import sys, codecs
import io

with open('top100.json') as f:
    data = f.read()
    fgh = json.loads(data)

print(fgh)
```

файл сохранён в формате unicode, utf-8 - не помогает. Содержимое файла валидное:

```
[[1, "joke1"], [2, "шутка"]]
```

Подскажите как решить проблему?

Comment: выложите куда-нибудь JSON файл, который поможет воспроизвести проблему. Если я создаю файл с указанным содержимым - у меня ваш код работает правильно

Comment: Ссылка для скачивания файла https://yadi.sk/d/PXaA_LMA37H82H

Answer (score 2):

Обычно данная ошибка указывает на то, что JSON файл содержит ошибки (invalid).

Как проверить (пример) - запустить в коммандеой строке:

```
python -m json.tool a.json
Expecting value: line 1 column 34 (char 33)
```

a.json:

```
[[1, "joke1"], [2, "шутка"],]
#                          ^
#                          |
```

PS я специально добавил запятую, чтобы показать как работает `json.tool`

Comment: MaxU, спасибо за комментарий. После выполнения в командной строке, результат такой: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 0: invalid start byte. Это если файл сохранить в кодировке ANSII. Если сохранить в utf-8, то выдает No Json object could be decoded. Почему не распознает файл не понятно, содержимое точно совпадает со строкой [[1, "joke1"], [2, "шутка"]]

Answer (score 1):

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 0: invalid start byte

Проблема у вас в том, что файл с json текстом сохранён, используя cp1251 кодировку, а `json.loads()` по умолчанию ожидает utf-8 кодировку.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import io

with io.open('top100.json', encoding='cp1251') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```

Лучше utf-8 использовать для json текста, чтобы поддерживать любые Unicode символы.

Answer (score 0):

Переустановка python 2.7 частично решила проблему. Также удалось выяснить, что проблема в кириллице. Если файл изменить вот так:

```
[[1, "joke1"], [2, "joke"]]
```

то все корректно распознается, если оставить кириллицу, то ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\guest_user\Documents\test json code.py", line 8, in <module>
    **fgh = json.loads(data)**
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Следующий код отрабатывает:

```
import sys  
import json
import codecs
import io

with codecs.open('top100.json') as f:
    data = f.read().decode("cp1251", "replace")
    print(data)
    fgh = json.loads(data)
print(fgh)
```

Но русские символы не выводит:

```
[[1, u'joke1'], [2, u'\u0448\u0443\u0442\u043a\u0430']]
```

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить на русский u'\u0448\u0443\u0442\u043a\u0430' ?**

Comment: советую почитать о [Unicode в Python 2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) или перейти на Python 3.x ;-)

Comment: про `u'\u0448..'` см. [Как json-данные \u0413\u0440... преобразовать в русский текст](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/606885/23044)