# Преобразование юникод–строки в исходное понятное человеку представление

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

На входе имеется массив «строк» (юникод–объектов):

```
words = [u"привет", u"мир"]
```

Моя задача — хитрым образом обработать их как одну строку:

```
text = process_text(u' '.join(words))
```

Далее разбить обратно на слова и поместить в список:

```
words = [word for word in text.split()]
```

Проблема в том, что на последнем этапе после выполнения метода `split`, строки из `u"привет"` и `u"мир"` превращаются в `u'\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442'` и `u'\u043c\u0438\u0440'`, но мне необходимо иметь исходное представление. Каким образом этого добиться?

**Обновление**

Для выявления проблемного места ставил вывод строки в консоль. Перед `process_text`, строка выводится в нужном формате, после — тоже, проблема появляется только после метода `split`.

**Обновление 2**

На всех этапах тип переменной `text` – `<type 'unicode'>`. Если сравнить «человеческое представление» и юникод–строку "привет", то сравнение работает верно. На данной стадии решения вопроса хотелось бы все–таки как–то получить не юникод–строку, а человеческое представление.

Comment: больше похоже на то, что это среда их так показывает просто или где ты смотришь. Так как в самой строке не важно. Попробуй в файл записать или на экран вывести

Comment: Не, на самом деле все в порядке. Разницы нет. Можешь попробовать вывести результат `u'\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442' == u"привет"` и увидишь, что все нормально. Это просто проблема при выводе в массиве. Если будешь выводить конкретный элемент, вывод будет нормальным

Comment: Какой тип переменной ‘text’ после вызова process_text?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как json-данные \u0413\u0440... преобразовать в русский текст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/606885/23044)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблемы с выводом, как оказалось, заключается в том, что в Python 2 необходимо выводить *именно строку, а не массив* (в Python 3 вывод массива через `print` работает превосходно).

То есть надо не

```
print(words)
```

Надо

```
print(u' '.join(words))
```

Тогда выводимая строка содержит `"привет мир"`.