# Как найти и преобразовать ASCII код в строке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Есть скрипт, который получает данные с сайта (пытаюсь получить название трека с twitch-dj) и обрабатывает их (просто извлекается часть строки). 
Проблема заключается в том, что на этом сайте русские символы хранятся в виде кода. То есть, на выходе я получаю такую строку, в которой всё, кроме кириллицы, отображается как надо:

```
"\u041c\u0430\u043c\u043a\u0430 \u043d\u0435 \u043a\u0443\u043f\u0438\u043b\u0430 \u0414\u0438\u0430\u0431\u043b\u0443 - AleXDarkstalker98"
```

Должно быть так:

```
"Мамка не купила Диаблу - AleXDarkstalker98"
```

Я не особо силён в Python и не могу придумать как правильно обработать строку так, чтоб преобразовать код символов в сами символы

Comment: Во-первых, это не имеет никакого отношения к ASCII. Во-вторых, я подозреваю, что вы пытаетесь рубить JSON-объект на части — почему бы вам не распарсить всё json-парсером по-нормальному?

Comment: > Во-первых, это не имеет никакого отношения к ASCII
>>Да, точно. Просто уже около полутора суток сижу, настраивая всякое, и мозг плавится :(

> почему бы вам не распарсить всё json-парсером по-нормальному?
>>Я просто не был уверен, что это вообще json-объект :( Как уже сказал, Python колупаю где-то третий день всего. Спасибо большое, разобрался. Всё работает

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как json-данные \u0413\u0440... преобразовать в русский текст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/606885/23044)

Comment: Вообще-то все нормально. Интерпретатор, или IDE может так (юникодом) показывать русские буквы. Вывод на экран (если там русский настроен), или в файл должен показать русский текст. Или это уже строчка с символами, а не с юникодом?

Answer (score -1):

```
#For python3

import json
import io
text = '\u041c\u0430\u043c\u043a\u0430 \u043d\u0435 \u043a\u0443\u043f\u0438\u043b\u0430 \u0414\u0438\u0430\u0431\u043b\u0443 - AleXDarkstalker98'
io.open("APIuz.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8").write(json.dumps(text, ensure_ascii=False))
print(open("APIuz.txt", "r").read())

#For python2

print(repr(u'\u041c\u0430\u043c\u043a\u0430 \u043d\u0435 \u043a\u0443\u043f\u0438\u043b\u0430 \u0414\u0438\u0430\u0431\u043b\u0443 - AleXDarkstalker98').decode('unicode-escape'))

#Код это то, что вы думаете

#>>> "Мамка не купила Диаблу - AleXDarkstalker98"
```